# Why is std::cout not printing the correct value for my int8_t number?

Tags: c++, gdb, cout

I have something like:

```
int8_t value;
value = -27;

std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

When I run my program I get a wrong random value of `<E5>` outputted to the screen, but when I run the program in gdb and use `p value` it prints out -27, which is the correct value.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: use [`std::cout << +value`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414758/995714)

Comment: @phuclv very cool, great one for template code

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because `int8_t` is the same as `signed char`, and `char` is not treated as a number by the stream. Cast into e.g. `int16_t`

```
std::cout << static_cast<int16_t>(value) << std::endl;
```

and you'll get the correct result.

Comment: since the type of int16_t may not be an integer (as the stream understands it) maybe you should case to `int`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because int8_t is synonymous to *signed* char.

So the value will be shown as a char value.

To force int display you could use

```
std::cout << (int) 'a' << std::endl;
```

This will work, as long as you don't require special formatting, e.g.

```
std::cout << std::hex << (int) 'a' << std::endl;
```

In that case you'll get artifacts from the widened size, especially if the char value is negative (you'd get FFFFFFFF or FFFF<sup>1</sup> for `(int)(int8_t)-1` instead of FF)

**Edit** see also this very readable writeup that goes into more detail and offers more strategies to 'deal' with this: http://blog.mezeske.com/?p=170

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> depending on architecture and compiler</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Most probably `int8_t` is

```
typedef char int8_t
```

Therefore when you use stream out "value" the underlying type (a char) is printed.

One solution to get a "integer number" printed is to type cast value before streaming the int8_t:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(value) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is printing out the value as a character - If you use 'char value;' instead, it prints the same thing.  int8_t is from the C standard library, so it may be that cout is not prepared for it(or it is just typedefd to char).