# OpenCV Display Pixels Value

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel

I have below code. When I run the program, unknown characters instead of pixel values comes to the screen. I want  to display pixel values. How do I do this? Thank you.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("/home/fd/baby.jpg");
    for( int i = 0 ; i < image.rows ; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < image.cols ; j++ )
        {
            if(image.type() == CV_8UC1)
            {
                image.at<uchar>(i,j) = 255;
            }
            else if(image.type() == CV_8UC3)
            {
                cout << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] << " " << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] << " " << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] << endl;

                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = 255;
                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = 255;
                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = 255;

                cout << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] << " " << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] << " " << image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Anknown image format" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    imshow("Result İmage", image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

This is the result screen:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is std::cout not printing the correct value for my int8\_t number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587782/why-is-stdcout-not-printing-the-correct-value-for-my-int8-t-number)

Comment: But you know picture of pixels have values between 0 and 255. So I think my problem is not signed or unsigned pixel value.

Comment: `cout << int(uchar_value);` but better even, just print the whole Mat: `cout << img << endl;`

Comment: It's not about signed or unsigned. Any flavour of `char` is printed as a single character not a number by default. Promoting to a bigger type prevents this. (If `cout << 'A'` printed 65 it would cause confusion. Blame backward compatibility.)

Comment: Thank you @berak, I solved my problem wity your answer. Thank you.

 cout << int(image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0])

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why "cout" works weird for "unsigned char"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374773/why-cout-works-weird-for-unsigned-char)

Comment: @AlanStokes `Vec3b` is `Vec<uchar, 3>`, not `Vec<int8_t, 3>`. So it's not a duplicate to what you link. :)

Comment: why are you assigning 255 each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vec3b px= image.at(x,y);

cout << "value: ("<<(int)px.val[0]<<", "<<(int)px.val[1]<<", "<<(int)px.val[2]<<")" << endl;

This works form me.

Answer (score 5):

Cast each of the outputs to an integer

```
<< image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] ...
```

change to

```
<< (int)image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] ...
```

You are printing a `char` (or probably `unsigned char`) which is printed through the stream as a single character (which at 255 looks like what you see). Cast to `int` forces it to display the numerical representation of the value.

The other answers changing the `image.at<type>` changes how the raw data is interpreted; don't do that. They must be interpreted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

`image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)`

to

`image.at<int>(i, j)`

or

`image.at<double>(i, j)`

or

`image.at<float>(i, j)`

to print the values instead of characters

Answer (score -2):

You are displaying characters try converting using function `image.at<int>(j,i);`