# How to use int point to struct in c

Tags: c++, pointers

i use `int8_t*` to point the struct,and i can use `cout` to print the "`num`" data, but how to print the "`b`" data?

here is my code

```
struct A_T{
    int num;
    char *b;
};
int main()
{
    A_T *a=new A_T();
    a->num=10;
    a->b="aaa";
    int8_t *p;
    p=(int8_t*)a;
    cout<<a->num<<endl;
    cout<<*p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`cout<<*p<<endl` can print the "`num`" data is 10, but when i use `cout<<*(p+1)<<endl` to print "`b`" data, it prints nothing.

can you help me ?

thank you

Comment: Why? Why not just use `a` to print the struct. In any case you probably need to investigate the `offsetof` macro.

Comment: because some method need int8_t point args

Comment: `*p` doesn't print anything on mine

Comment: _`cout<<*p<<endl` can print the "num" data is 10_ - no it doesn't. The 10 comes from `cout<<a->num<<endl;`

Comment: @tianyu Then change those methods so they don't use integer pointers.

Comment: @churill yes,i got wrong, *p doesn't print anything

Comment: @tianyu john's answer is good and if you want to know why `*p` doesn't seem to print anything: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587782/why-is-stdcout-not-printing-the-correct-value-for-my-int8-t-number

Comment: Instead of `a->num = 10;` try `a->num = 3000;`. You'll see that `std::cout << *p` **doesn't** print the value of `num`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use from this 'cout << ((A_T *)p)->b<<endl;' instraction inorderto access member b of struct.

Answer (score 4):

It's painful but this might work for you

```
#include <stddef.h>

cout << *(char**)(p + offsetof(A_T, b)) << '\n';
```